# How to read content of shared spotify playlist without installing it?

Tags: spotify

In my country I don't have spotify service and neither I have installation rights/permissions on the system am using but I want to extract the song name/artist metatdata from a spotify playlist shared on subbreddit `/r/spotify`.

For, example a user shared his playlist on `/r/spotify` http://open.spotify.com/user/1224703396. Now as soon as you visit the above page it asks for `do you have spotify installed`.

So, is it possible to extract content from user shared playlists using spotify API or is there any online service which does that.

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct web API for doing this. However, two workarounds come to mind:

1) Use libspotify or CocoaLibSpotify and write a little application do do it.

2) Create a [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) widget with the playlist's URL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but doesn't `libspotify or CocoaLibSpotify` requires an API key which is only for the `premium users`. So, is it even available for the non-premium/free users and about the 2nd suggestion how do I get playlist url because it's not my playlist  all I have is the above user(3rd person) shared playlist link.

Comment: To convert an open link to a Spotify URI you replace `open.spotify.com` with `spotify` and slashes with colons. So your link `http://open.spotify.com/user/1224703396` becomes `spotify:user:1224703396`. The link is to a user, not a playlist, so it won't work with the Play Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the official website of Spotify: https://open.spotify.com/, enter the playlist link in the Spotify search bar.
For more details, you can read this article: [How to Listen to Music on Spotify Web](https://www.tunelf.es/spotify-music/como-escuchar-musica-en-spotify-web.html)